# Drupal <front> tag not working on menu link

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm new to Drupal CMS. Here I want to set front page link for main menu item. It set that  for front page link as per Drupal guide. But, it gives an unexpected result example.com/.

Is there any way to display any front page or blank for my main menu item eg: example.com?

Note that I'm using a custom theme.

Comment: I manually get menus using drupal_get_path_alias() function. It this a problem or not?

Answer (score 0):

By default Drupal doesn't add slash if  tag is used. You can try checking your rewrite rules.

Comment: what kind rules are need to configure in .htaccess

Comment: Can you provide your .htaccess content for homepage ?